# Nomencl not being printed no nls file

Tags: printing, nomencl, makeidx

Written article, but nomenclature is not printed. Using Texmaker with MikTEX. I have configured the Makeindex file locations as in the examples.

```
makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls
```

Commands used (and lots of others):

```
PDFLaTeX
MakeIndex
BibTex
PDFLaTeX
PDFLaTeX
```

An example nomenclature was printed once, but never again. Re-entered everything into new file. Removed nomencl package and let it be reinstalled. Tried out on 2nd PC, but issue remains. Tried another example as below and still does not work.

Files generated are *.aux, *.log, *.nlo, *.bbl, *.blg, *.synctex and *.pdf. All in same directory as the test file. There is no *.nls file.

Simplest of the examples used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\nomenclature{test}{This is a test}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Comment: TeXMaker usually wants a `%` instead of `<filename>`. Thus using `makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls` as the definition of your makeindex command should work.

Comment: your `\nomenclature{}{}` is outside your `document`. it needs to be inside.

Answer (score 1):

MWE on how to use `nomenclature`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
    \chapter{foo}
    
    \nomenclature{$\gamma$}{Greek alphabetical symbol}
    
    \printnomenclature
    
\end{document}
```

Compile document by running a makefile containing:

```
PDFLaTeX
makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls%
BibTeX
PDFLaTeX
PDFLaTeX
```

Comment: Many thanks to all. Yep works with % and not <filename>.  I think I tried % as well, but I may have over written it. I much appreciate the answers, not being in an academic setting (writing up old research work in covid times) I had no one to ask.

Comment: as a token of gratitude, it's customary to accept the answer and simply upvote it.